# How to extract alternate rows from a table which has two rows(Employ_id, salary)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with two rows(employeeId, salary), Now I want to extract alternate rows(even or odd) from that table. how to write code in sql?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as "even rows" or "odd rows" (or "first row" or "last row") unless you specify a column that contains that ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering of the table, then you can use variables to do what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from table t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) vars
      order by col
     ) t
where mod(seqnum, 2) = 0;
```

Comment: there is no any extra column to ordering the table. then how to get alternate rows as output.

Answer (score 0):

ODD ROWS,

select * from
(select empno, ename, sal, rownum rn
from emp
order by empno)
where  mod (rn, 2) <> 0;

EVEN ROWS

select * from
(select empno, ename, sal, rownum rn
from emp
order by empno)
where  mod (rn, 2) = 0;

Comment: small correction that is not rows ...those are columns...table with two columns with (employee_id, salary) so how can we show alternate rows.

Comment: You meant to say you need a column as row ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no such thing as "even" and "odd" rows.  If I interpret the question as wanting rows where `employeeid` is even or odd, I would use:

```
where mod(employeeid, 2) = 0  -- or 1 or odd
```

If I interpret it as wanted rows -- ordered by `employeeid` -- were even or odd, then I would enumerate the rows.  In the most recent versions of MySQL:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by employeeid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where mod(seqnum, 2) = 0;   -- or 1 for odd
```